# Visual Studio Code wont launch Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

i downloaded Vs Code for mac but it simply doesn´t open. I tried downloading it in several ways but it didnt work.It opens for a sec and then it closes up.  I also tried installing vs code insiders but i get a " finder could not open code insiders ". My Os is mojave

Answer (score 0):

have you tried downloading from github? and, this is *very* silly to ask, but have you tried restarting? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

i've had a lot of software bugs (e.g. nodejs for vscode) that were fixed by restarts

Comment: I tried the restarting and it didnt work either haha , but ill give the github download a try to see if it works